What symbol should I use for non linear proportional to?
Until now, if I had a function $f$ and a monotonic transformation of it $g$, I would write $f \propto g$, however, a colleague of mine pointed out that it's usually considered "proportional to" a linear proportionality, so something like the logarithm would not fall in this category.
Given this, which symbol should I use?

choice of notation isn't normally considered on topic here, just how to typeset that in tex once you have chosen.

@DavidCarlisle ops, do you reckon that there are better changes to ask this question?..

math stackexchange, perhaps

There is no such thing as "non-linearly proportional to". I am not aware of any term, let alone notation, for the situation in which $g$ is a monotonic transformation of $f$.

I've never seen any specific notation for this. If you want to express a logarithmic relationship, for instance, you could write $f \propto \log g$.

@Sambo yes, in particular i was dealing with likelihoods and loglikelihoods, which as the name says, it's just a log transformation, but since $\propto$ refers to "proportionality", they were saying that usually that term means "linearly proportional to"

@BenGrossmann Indeed, what I want to say is something like "$f$ increases as $g$ increases", which to me seems a notion of proportionality, though maybe not for everybody

When-ever $x$ increases , you want $f(x)$ to increase too : You could use the notation $\Delta f(x) \gt 0$ , where it is Implicitly $\forall x$. Depending on Choice , you can write it Explicitly too $\forall x : \Delta f(x) \gt 0$ , alternatively $\Delta f(x) \gt 0 , \forall x$.

@Prem but that doesnt say anything about $g$… ideally i’d like something like $f(x_1)<f(x_2) \rightarrow g(x_1) < g(x_2)$, so for sure the derivatives are positive

In my Comment , I had meant [[ $f$ "Is Proportional" to $x$ ]] , while when I want [[ $f$ "Is Proportional" to $g$ ]] then I may want to use $\Delta f(g) \gt 0 , \forall g$

We may continue to the limit where we have $df/dx \gt 0$ or $f' \gt 0$ or $df/dg \gt 0$ or $f'/g' \gt 0$ , where we may include $\forall x$ or $\forall g$. Eg $x^2 \propto \log x$ is $d[x^2]/d[\log x] \gt 0$ which is indeed true $[2x]/[1/x]=2x^2 \gt 0$ !!
